# Selecting a range of columns in Python without using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract range of columns. I know how to do that in numpy but I don't want to use numpy slicing operator.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
arr = np.array(a)

k = 0

print(arr[k:, k+1]) # --> [2 7]
print([[a[r][n+1] for n in range(0,k+1)] for r in range(k,len(a))][0]) # --> [2]
```

What's wrong with second statement?

Comment: `[row[k:k+1] for row in a]` ?

Comment: Just move [0] to the end of the other list comprehension and that will be OK

Comment: @mathfux works with k=0, but breaks when k = 1. Is there any function to extract range of column without using numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it. Get the rows with `a[k:]`, then get a  cell with `row[k+1]`.

```
>>> [row[k+1] for row in a[k:]]
[2, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
cols = [1,2,3] # extract middle 3 columns
cols123 = [[l[col] for col in cols] for l in a]
# [[2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
k = 0
print(list(list(zip(*a[k:]))[k+1])) # [2, 7]
```